# What should an English writer from a non-English speaking country be called?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What should an English writer from another country be called?

For instance, a Spanish person migrates to England and starts writing novels in English. Should we call him "a Spanish-English novel writer"?

Comment: You might look up real world examples like Kerouac and Nabokov, and see how they're referred to.  You might also look up *exophony* for further discussion.

Comment: He's just [a native speaker of] Spanish, who *writes in English*. But his nationality (and possibly his "mother tongue", assuming he writes English well enough not to detract from the quality of his work) isn't really relevant. Do you expect special different "standard terms" to refer to *female* novelists? (not to mention *gay, black, religious* or whatever).#

Comment: Collectively, people who write in a language other than their mother tongue are [***exophonic writers***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_exophonic_writers). In the *specific* context of providing a list, Wikipedia identifies Joseph Conrad as a ***Polish-British novelist***. But in other contexts I might just as likely assume all it meant was that Conrad had dual nationality, with no *specific* implications about what language(s) he wrote novels in.

Answer (score 0):

Question: For instance, a Spanish person migrates to England and starts writing novels in English. Should we call him "a Spanish-English novel writer"?

Answer: No, he is Spanish and writes in English.

Spanish, English, French, Chinese, Cape Verdean etc. are nationalities.

Writers write in a language.

- Samuel Becket was Irish and he wrote in French.
- Vladimir Nabokov was (originally) Russian and wrote in English.
- Joseph Conrad was (originally) Polish and wrote in English.

However, if you only have the nationality, it is assumed the person is writing in the language of that country.

- She is an American writer.
- Those are French writers.
- He is a Spanish writer.
- Her father was a Russian writer.

Comment: Brittanica calls Joseph Conrad an "English novelist and short-story writer of Polish descent". Apparently "English novelist" can refer to an adopted nationality.

Comment: @JamesK It is commonly recognized that he was not a native English speaker. Like I said, English novelist there means of English nationality.